# How can I claim ranges of integers to assign to an entity using a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that manages lists of recipients. Each list of recipients needs to be assigned a block of serial numbers that are guaranteed to be unique for the last 90 days. A serial number is simply an integer between 1 and 999999.

I don't have to track which serial number gets associated with which recipient. There could be 500K+ recipients per list.

I have the following tables:

**ListJob**

```
    ListJobId int PK
    ListJobName varchar(64)
```

**Recipient**

```
    RecipientId int PK
    ListJobId int FK
    Name varchar(64)
```

**ListJobSerialRange**

```
    ListJobSerialRangeId int PK
    ListJobId int FK
    DateClaimed datetime
    SerialNumberStart int
    SerialNumberEnd int
```

The `ListJobSerialRange` table stores the claimed serial number range(s) that will be assigned to the recipients in the application layer. The sum of all the ranges that are assigned to a list job must equal the number of recipients, as each recipient will ultimately be assigned one serial number.

Recipients can be added and removed from a `ListJob` frequently. If we add recipients, we will need to claim additional serial numbers for them. If we remove recipients we want to free up the claimed serial numbers so we can re-use them so we don't waste serial numbers within the 90 day period.

Each list job will ultimately have one set of ranges. It won't have some that are claimed before the 90 days and some that are after the 90 days.

Here's a quick example:

- Possible serial numbers are 1 to 999,999.
- ListJob A has claimed 1 to 10,000
- ListJob B has claimed 10,501 to 20,500

Now ListJob C has 1000 recipients. It needs to claim TWO ranges to fulfill all recipients:

```
10,001 to 10,500 
20,501 to 21,000
```

Here's what I have so far for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClaimSerialNumbers]
    @ListJobId int,
    @NumDaysUnique int,
    @MaxSerialNumber int
as begin
    set nocount on

    declare @RecipientCount int
    declare @QuantityClaimed int
    declare @QuantityNeeded int
    declare @DateThreshold smalldatetime

    set @DateThreshold = dateadd(day, 0-@NumDaysUnique, getdate())

    select  @RecipientCount = count(*)
    from    dbo.Recipient
    where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

    select  @QuantityClaimed = sum(SerialNumberEnd - SerialNumberStart + 1)
    from    dbo.ListJobSerialRange
    where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

    set @QuantityNeeded = @QuantityClaimed - @RecipientCount

    if (@QuantityNeeded < 0) begin
        delete  dbo.ListJobSerialRange
        where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

        set @QuantityNeeded = @RecipientCount
    end

    if (@QuantityNeeded = 0) begin
        -- if we run the sproc twice and nothing has changed, then nothing to do
        return 0
    end

    -- now the hard part:
    -- i need to claim some serial numbers
    -- ???
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got something I think will work.. First, I grab all of the claimed serial number ranges within the date threshold and sort them by the start number ascending and dump them in a temp table.  Then the next part is the key concept.. I can peek at the previous row and the next row.  That is a slight performance issue that i have to select from the temp table 3 times.  but there really shouldn't be that many in there since i have already narrowed it down to the ones that are greater than the date threshold.  then it's just a matter of looking at the cases where there can be gaps.

```
CREATE     PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClaimSerialNumbers]
    @ListJobId int,
    @NumDaysUnique int,
    @MaxSerialNumber int
as
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @RecipientCount int = 0
declare @QuantityClaimed int = 0
declare @QuantityNeeded int = 0
declare @Now smalldatetime = getdate()
declare @DateThreshold smalldatetime = dateadd(day, 0-@NumDaysUnique, @Now)
declare @RunningTotal int = 0
declare @UnusedRangeCount int = 0

--***************************************
-- Get number of recipients for list job
--***************************************
select  @RecipientCount = coalesce(count(*), 0)
from    dbo.Recipient with(nolock)
where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

--***************************************
-- get how many serial numbers are already claimed
--***************************************
select  @QuantityClaimed = coalesce(sum(SR.SerialNumberEnd - SR.SerialNumberStart + 1), 0)
from    dbo.ListJobSerialRange SR
where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

--***************************************
-- Determine how many we still need
--***************************************
set @QuantityNeeded = @QuantityClaimed - @RecipientCount    

--***************************************
-- if we have more claimed that number of recipients
-- we have deleted recipients and need to free up 
-- some serial numbers
--***************************************
if (@QuantityNeeded < 0) begin
    delete  dbo.ListJobSerialRange
    where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

    set @QuantityNeeded = @RecipientCount
end

--***************************************
-- if we need to claim some serial numbers
--***************************************
if (@QuantityNeeded > 0) begin
    if object_id('tempdb..#SortedRanges') is not null drop table #SortedRanges
    if object_id('tempdb..#UnusedRanges') is not null drop table #UnusedRanges
    create table #SortedRanges(RowNumber int, SerialNumberStart int, SerialNumberEnd int)
    create table #UnusedRanges(SerialNumberStart int, SerialNumberEnd int, RunningTotal int)

    --***************************************
    -- put all the existing ranges within the last N days into a temp table
    --***************************************
    insert  #SortedRanges
            (RowNumber, SerialNumberStart, SerialNumberEnd)
    select  RowNumber = row_number() over (order by SerialNumberStart)
                    , SerialNumberStart
                    , SerialNumberEnd
    from    dbo.ListJobSerialRange
    where   DateClaimed >= @DateThreshold
    order by SerialNumberStart

    --***************************************
    -- if no ranges exist in the last N days, then the whole set is available
    --***************************************
    if (@@rowcount = 0)
    begin
        insert  dbo.ListJobSerialRange
                (ListJobId, DateClaimed, SerialNumberStart, SerialNumberEnd)
        values  (@ListJobId, @Now, 1, @QuantityNeeded)
    end
    --***************************************
    -- if we have serial numbers that were used in the last n days
    -- then look for gaps in the rangesand add those gaps to the unused range temp table
    --***************************************
    else 
    begin
        ;with UnusedRangesFirstPass as (
            select  distinct
                    case 
                        -- start of range (gap at beginning)
                        when P.RowNumber is null and C.SerialNumberStart > 1 then 1
                        -- start of range (gap at end)
                        when N.RowNumber is null and C.SerialNumberEnd < @MaxSerialNumber then C.SerialNumberEnd + 1
                        -- start of range (middle row gaps)
                        else
                            case 
                                when P.SerialNumberEnd is not null and P.SerialNumberEnd < C.SerialNumberStart - 1 then P.SerialNumberEnd + 1
                                when N.SerialNumberStart is not null and N.SerialNumberStart > C.SerialNumberEnd + 1 then C.SerialNumberEnd + 1
                            end
                    end as UnusedStart,
                    case
                        -- end of range (gap at beginning)
                        when P.RowNumber is null and C.SerialNumberStart > 1 then (C.SerialNumberStart - 1)
                        -- end of range (gap at end)
                        when N.RowNumber is null and C.SerialNumberEnd < @MaxSerialNumber then @MaxSerialNumber
                        -- end of range (middle row gaps)
                        else
                            case
                                when P.SerialNumberEnd is not null and P.SerialNumberEnd < C.SerialNumberStart - 1 then C.SerialNumberStart - 1
                                when N.SerialNumberStart is not null and N.SerialNumberStart > C.SerialNumberEnd + 1 then N.SerialNumberStart - 1
                            end
                    end as UnusedEnd
            from #SortedRanges C -- current row
            left join #SortedRanges P ON P.RowNumber = C.RowNumber - 1 -- peek at previous row
            left join #SortedRanges N ON N.RowNumber = C.RowNumber + 1 -- peek at next row
        )
        insert  #UnusedRanges
                (SerialNumberStart, SerialNumberEnd, RunningTotal)
        select  UnusedStart, UnusedEnd, 0
        from    UnusedRangesFirstPass
        where   UnusedStart is not null 
                and UnusedEnd is not null

        --***************************************
        -- update all unused ranges and calculate a running total
        -- for each row
        --***************************************
        update  #UnusedRanges
        set     @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + (SerialNumberEnd - SerialNumberStart + 1)

        --***************************************
        -- claim the unused ranges.
        -- only claim the exact number we need
        --***************************************   
        insert  dbo.ListJobSerialRange
                (ListJobId, DateClaimed, SerialNumberStart, SerialNumberEnd)
        select  @ListJobId, @Now, UR1.SerialNumberStart, 
                case 
                    when UR1.RunningTotal > @QuantityNeeded then UR1.SerialNumberEnd - (UR1.RunningTotal - @QuantityNeeded)
                    else UR1.SerialNumberEnd
                end
        from    #UnusedRanges UR1
                left join #UnusedRanges UR2 on UR1.RunningTotal > UR2.RunningTotal
        group by UR1.SerialNumberStart, UR1.SerialNumberEnd, UR1.RunningTotal
        having coalesce(sum(UR2.RunningTotal),0) < @QuantityNeeded
    end
end

--***************************************
-- return results and commit
--***************************************   
select  ListJobSerialRangeId, ListJobId, DateClaimed, SerialNumberStart, SerialNumberEnd
from    dbo.ListJobSerialRange
where   ListJobId = @ListJobId

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

I would populate the table and then just do updates. Here is an example on allocating ranges

```
--Populate the table; only needs done once if not a table variable
DECLARE @ListJobSerialRange TABLE
(
    ListJobSerialRangeId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    SerialNumberStart int,
    SerialNumberEnd int,
    ListJobId int,
    DateClaimed datetime
 )

DECLARE @Counter BIGINT=1
WHILE @Counter<1000000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @ListJobSerialRange
    SELECT @Counter,@Counter+10000,NULL,NULL

  SET @Counter=@Counter+10000
END

-- manual update to show that it will skip ranges to get contiguous ranges
UPDATE @ListJobSerialRange 
SET ListJobId = 9999,DateClaimed=GETDATE()
WHERE ListJobSerialRangeId=1

-- manual update to show that it will skip ranges to get contiguous ranges
UPDATE @ListJobSerialRange 
SET ListJobId = 9929,DateClaimed=GETDATE()
WHERE ListJobSerialRangeId=3



-- this is where my sproc would begin
DECLARE @ListJobSerialRangeIds TABLE(
  ListJobSerialRangeId INT
)


DECLARE @MaxListJobSerialRange INT
SELECT @MaxListJobSerialRange=MAX(ListJobSerialRangeID) FROM @ListJobSerialRange

DECLARE @SerialNumbersNeeded INT = 20001
DECLARE @BlocksNeeded INT= (@SerialNumbersNeeded / 10000) + (@SerialNumbersNeeded % 10000)
DECLARE @ContBlocksAvail INT=0

SET @Counter=1
WHILE @Counter<=@MaxListJobSerialRange AND @ContBlocksAvail<>@BlocksNeeded
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM @ListJobSerialRange
      WHERE ListJobSerialRangeID = @Counter
      AND ListJobId IS NULL
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ListJobSerialRangeIds SELECT @Counter

        SET @ContBlocksAvail=@ContBlocksAvail+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @ContBlocksAvail=0
      DELETE @ListJobSerialRangeIds
    END

    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
END

UPDATE l
SET ListJobId = 1123,DateClaimed=GETDATE()
FROM @ListJobSerialRange l
INNER JOIN @ListJobSerialRangeIds ids on ids.ListJobSerialRangeId=l.ListJobSerialRangeId


SELECT * FROM @ListJobSerialRange
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... My main concern with this approach is performance.. basically you are using a cursor approach (while loop) and performing many queries on the table.  my table isn't actually a table variable, rather it's an actual table.

Comment: @Donuts You did need the serial number blocks to be contiguous, correct? Also, with only 100 rows in the table and a 90 day lock on a block, I don't see performance being an issue here if the situation is as described.

Comment: Yes, i do need them to be contiguous.. You may be right that there could be a small set of rows.. the worst case scenario would be there are 999,999 rows if there were that many list jobs with a single recipient.. so each with a range of 1 serial number.  I don't like to assume there will be a small set of rows.